# How to retrieve data model attribute from my activity_log table to my blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

It's my first time using Spatie package. I have successfully integrated the Spatie package, a package for activity log,  to my code and insert the data to my activity_log table when a user successfully logs in. Still, I need to figure out how to display the data from my activity_log table database to my blade.php file to display it on my table views when I dont have activity_log model.

this is the migration file :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateActivityLogTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection(config('activitylog.database_connection'))->create(config('activitylog.table_name'), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('log_name')->nullable();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->nullableMorphs('subject', 'subject');
            $table->nullableMorphs('causer', 'causer');
            $table->json('properties')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->index('log_name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection(config('activitylog.database_connection'))->dropIfExists(config('activitylog.table_name'));
    }
}
```

this is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;


class UserLogsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('user_logs', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

this is my activity_log table from my database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTI0F.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the spatie package [`Laravel-activitylog`](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction) it comes with trait which will allow you to access logs for each model.

You should use the trait `LogsActivity` on the model which you want to log activities.

In case you want to log activities performs on a user model, you can first use the Trait `LogsActivity` on the `User` model.

use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

```
class User extends Model {
    use LogsActivity;    
}
```

This trait will allow your model to have access to `activities` by calling `$user->activities` which will return all activities performed on that `$user`.

> Learn more [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/advanced-usage/logging-model-events) and how to attach the trait to the model